# ios - UIAlertView and longpress event (UILongPressGestureRecognizer)

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile, uialertview

I’m doing a simple application in which I have a button with a long press event attached to it - UILongPressGestureRecognizer.
When I long press this button, I open up a UIAlertView.

The problem is: when the UIAlertView is shown, the UILongPressGestureRecognizer state is changed to UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled.

Is there any way of avoiding this? Or is there some other approach of doing it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: In what state is the gesture recognizer when the UIAlertView is opened?

Comment: @danh the state is Began (UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)

Comment: No, at the point that you choose to open the alert.  What is it then?  Also, what state do you want/expect it to be in and why?